# how to change the font color of a list based on the column?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, css

I have a sharepoint list with four columns. I need to change the color of fonts of each column based on the column header. how do i do that ?

please see the image below for more infomation

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate your question so one can understand your problem. Use css with nth-child property. You can get reference from here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Have you looked at using JSLink? https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: how do i use nth child with a list?